# Pylance can't resolve the import of a library under same package

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pylance, vscode-python

I am using VSCode and Pylance. I have the following workspace

```
- src
  - company
    - __init__.py
    - team
      - __init__.py
      - project
        - __init__.py
        - A.py
        - B.py
```

And I have some libraries that I import in `A.py` like this

```
from company.team import library1
```

since my workspace also contains `company.team`, Pylance tries to find `library1` in my workspace.

If I do the following, pylance looks at the correct place (`/lib/python3.8`) and it works.

```
from company.team.library1 import foo
```

I have the correct path for `python.autoComplete.extraPaths`, so that is not an issue.

Any help?

Comment: Use absolute path

Comment: My use case is perfectly valid and I'd rather not use hacky solutions just to appease pylance.

Comment: I'm sorry to reply to you after such a long time. Vscode is retrieved with the workspace as the root directory. You can use "sys path. append()".

Comment: I came to the same conclusion recently. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vscode is retrieved with the workspace as the root directory. You can use `sys path. append()`.